# Why can't I add features to the default instance of MS SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server

I currently have a MS SQL 2008 server installation with two instances "MSSQLSERVER" and "MSSQLSERVER2".  When I run the installation CD/Setup and attempt to add new features, I get to the screen where you are supposed to select the instance you want to add features to, but it will ONLY allow me to select "MSSQLSERVER2".  This is a problem as I wish to add full text search to "MSSQLSERVER", which I cannot select.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

The default instance is typically called "MSSQLSERVER"  if you choose that during install.  If you create other instances, then I would recommend a name like "INST2", "SQLEXPRESS1", or "SQLEXPRESS"  instead of something that uses the substring "MSSQLSERVER".   As a guess, I would say your probably running into an issue with the installer not recognizing some kind of reserved word that identifies the instance.

Comment: Yes, I have "MSSQLSERVER" which is the default instance.  I also have "MSSQLSERVER2" which is another named instance.  I fail to see any logical reason why these two names have anything to do with why I cannot install additional features on the default instance.

Answer (score 0):

Is full text search already installed on the default instance?

Have you tried to start the service in the SQL configuration manager?

Comment: No, full text search in not installed on the default instance.  I have verified this with the query: SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled'), which returns 0.  The only instance of the service in the configuration manager is for the MSSQLSERVER2 instance, so it is irrelevant.